# how to display database value in console in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

How to display the unitfunction value from mysql database and my query is below ,i don't know its right or wrong.
Help me out.

```
 string fundev = "select unitfunctioncode from channels where channel_no = " + Channelid;
                    MySqlCommand getfun = new MySqlCommand(fundev, Connection1);
                    Console.WriteLine(getfun);
```

Comment: Why you don't use `LINQ` for this

Comment: No idea about that, Can you provide some code?

Answer (score 0):

MAKE `ENTITY CONTEXT` FIRST:
    YourEntity db= new YourEntity();
**LINQ:**

```
Console.Write(db.channels.Where(x=>x.channel_no == Channelid).Select(y=>y.unitfunctioncode));
```

This is modal first approach create modal from database and call this `linq` in controller

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the specifics of MySqlCommand, but I would expect to see an `execute` on your getfun object.

I would do something like this:

```
MySqlDataReader rdr = getfun.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(rdr[0]);
}
rdr.Close();
```

This takes into account multiple rows returned. You can omit the while loop if you're sure you will have a single row returned.